# Where can I find dashboard widgets on OS Catalina?

Tags: mission-control, catalina, dashboard-widget, dashboard

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: dashboard widgets]

I couldn't find it anymore, I used to set it as a hot corner in **System Preferences > Mission Control**, I tried to search the keyword "Dashboard" in System Preferences but ended with no luck. Did Apple remove Dashboard on OS Catalina? If not, where can I find it? Thanks a lot!

Edit: 
Seems like dashboard is removed from OS Catalina (thanks to the comment linking to other similar questions!), **Is there any way to put dashboard widgets on desktop like it's shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m57oX0Cc1s)?**

UPDATE:

**Is there a way to get the Converter Tool somehow?** (the widget that can convert currency, length, pressure, weight all in one!) Recommendation of similar Apps is welcomed too!

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of articles that say that dashboard is not there on Catalina https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=dashboard%20catalina see these  questions with different attempts to recover the features.

Comment: Some of these are now in Notifications, present on extremest right of menu bar. Click on that and you will be able to add/modify what is displayed. Only Stickies is to be found in Launchpad.

Comment: @Yoan Is there a way to get the Converter Tool somehow? Or something similar, that would allow multiple windows of different kinds of conversions? Unfortunately, Converter is one of the widgets I cannot found in Notifications... I noticed you can manually type what you want to convert in Spotlight, but that gets tedious after a while...

Comment: @kuku Convert tool is now embedded in Calculator application. It is the normal calculator, not the one available in Notifications. You can use it from there.

Comment: @Yoan Uh found it! Thanks a lot, mate! This is bad news for people who are used to the dashboard widget converter... I will miss it :(

Comment: Most conversions can be done directly in Spotlight search like "1kg in lbs" or "1 USD in EUR"

Answer (score 6):

Dashboard nor Widgets are available in macOS 10.15 Catalina. Since Widgets are not available I don't think the question of how to place them in the video is possible.